# How to add an image to my Gmail signature?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I know there is a plugin for Firefox but is there any other way to create a signature in Gmail that includes an image?

Comment: Please don't. Think of the bandwidth this is eating up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google recently introduced their "rich text signatures" feature for Gmail users (including Apps users):  [Official Gmail Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/07/rich-text-signatures.html).

From your inbox screen, click on "Settings" in the upper-right corner. Scroll down to the signature box, which is now a rich text editor just like the regular email editor. You should be able to add images, colorful text, and all kinds of things that are totally unnecessary for a wholly-textual experience like email.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks. I agree about the signature being text only but people ask for it all the time. I'm really glad it's not a labs feature . . . this way most people will discover it on their own! Except of course for the know-it-alls who don't go and check their options every week to see if Google added something new.