# Inline images in Gmail signatures?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, images, email-signature

I know [how to add an image to my Gmail signature](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/how-to-add-an-image-to-my-gmail-signature), but unless I'm mistaken, this image will not be included as an attachment and thus has to be externally hosted. Newer mail clients don't load external images by default, so my company would like everyone to use inline images. For those of us that use Gmail as God intended, in a Chrome browser, and not via Outlook, how can we create a signature that includes an inline image?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a draft ready with the signature to be used as a template every time you want to send a message (time consuming). Wisestamp will also use external hosted images (feature already in Gmail).

Considering all this, using a mail client is the only option if you want to use inline images in signature.

Answer (score 1):

I just got it to work using this ugly hack.

1. Add the image to a draft - it will be added as an attached/inline image
2. Inspect the html in the browser
3. Copy the html for the image tag
4. Go to settings and edit your signature
5. Inspect that signature in the browser.
6. Replace the existing image tag with the HTML you copied in step 3
7. To make sure your inspected changes are saved, edit the signature in the browser, add a space and remove it again to.
8. Click save at the bottom of the page

Now you can start a new draft where the image in the signature will be sent as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

According to multiple sources, **it is impossible to use inline images with the Gmail signature feature**.

> Gmail doesn’t support uploading images for signatures in the traditional manner. Therefore, you’ll have to link to a public image on the web.
>
> *[Dito - Make the Image in Your Gmail Signature a Working Hyperlink](https://www.ditoweb.com/blog/2014/04/make-image-in-your-gmail-signature/)*

and

> Now, importantly, you can't just upload an image straight from your computer to Google, they won't host the image for you, so we need to actually host the image on an external site.
>
> *[itGenius - Video: How to Embed an Image in your Gmail Signature](https://www.itgenius.com/how-to-embed-an-image-in-your-gmail-signature/)*

So in other words, Gmail *does not* allow inline images in the email signature feature. The only workaround is to keep a draft with your inline-image email signature in it, or to use a third-party Gmail extension to manage your inline-image signature.

Answer (score -2):

Inline images in signatures should be avoided. It wastes the recipients disk space, and if images are not deleted (most people are too lazy, ignorant or stupid to remove history/quoting) when replying, it eats away disk space and bandwidth at an increasing rate.

Comment: I don't understand the answer above re wasting disk space? I would think that including actual images (e.g., by dropping in images from the desktop, or bringing them in from the computer or a url) would waste more space? In fact, I tested both ways: inline and "online" and then checked the full message body of the recipient (myself at a different email address), and for sure the inline approach uses much less coding and disk space.

Answer (score -3):

You should try [WiseStamp](http://www.wisestamp.com/).

I know that, when you have an account, you can add image to your signature, but I cannot confirm whether is inline or online.

Comment: it's not inline.